# DataTable pagination page selected color

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, datatables

I'm using Ajax Datatable I want a css when i select a page when any page selected background color should be changed not just mouse hover or active . How I can do this . Here is my css code it is not I wanted .

```
 .dataTables_paginate :active {
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

Please Note it works only for page click . I want the page I  now should be different color . Thanks in advance
Here is My datatable code .

```
function LoadPaging() {
    $('#tblChannalList').DataTable({
        "searching": false,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "showNEntries": false,
        "dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
        //"dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
        //"sDom": 'RlfrtlipB',
        //"dom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>'
    });

    return;
}
```

And Here is my css code

```
.paginatebutton {
    background-color: white;
}



.dataTables_paginate {
    width: 270px;
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 340px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    /*float: left !important;*/
}
    .dataTables_paginate:active {
        background-color: blue;
        color:red;
    }
    .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current {
        background: blue !IMPORTANT;
    }
/*.pagination .page-item.current .page-link {
    background-color: #000;
}*/
.pagination .page-item.active .page-link {
    background-color: #000;
}

div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_paginate ul.pagination .page-item.active .page-link:focus {
    background-color: #000;
}

.pagination .page-item.active .page-link:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Update your css with below. you have extra space between `:active`.

```
.dataTables_paginate:active {
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

If that dont work then this will do.

```
.dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current {
    background: blue !IMPORTANT;
}
```

Comment: not worked . do I need js code to change the currently selected page @Sumit Patel

Comment: no data table add a current class to the active page so second solution should work i test on there site. can you please add your code i can check.

Comment: try this .pagination .page-item.active {background-color: blue !important;}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197674/discussion-between-sumit-patel-and-rifat-murtuza).